# Using Multithreading with parameterized function passing object array as parameter

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, function, parameterized

I have created an structure as below

```
Public Structure Emu
  Dim a As Object
  Dim b As Object
  Dim c As Object
  Dim d As Object
End Structure
```

Now I have declared an array of structure emu as below

```
Public x(25) As Emu
```

Now I have a button named `goEMU` and I have added the code in the click event of the button as below:

```
Public Sub goEMU_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles goEMU.click
    ******Some work 
    Set Index as cc based on some custom criteria
    DoMyJob(x(cc),y) 
    *****Some work 
End Sub
```

In my personalized sub I have this code:

```
Sub DoMyJob(ByRef f As Emu, ByVal z As Integer)

****Do some work

End Sub
```

Now I want to create a thread which will control the sub `DoMyJob` and the thread will start within `goEMU_Click`.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to call the `AddressOf DoMyJob` with the parameters as described above.

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First what is the problem? Do you get an error? Why can't you just pass the parameters to a lambda?  *Most importantly, Why* do you want a thread? Why don you use Tasks and just call `Task.Run` ?

Comment: I have tried using lambda as below
addressof(sub()
                          DoMyJob(x,y)
                 end sub)
but it did not do the job. 
I want threading as in my application I need to stop the work as per user choice in between the run.
I am new to this forum, so Please excuse me for mistakes.

Comment: If `emo` is an array, then `DoMyJob(x,y)`, passing the entire array to a sub which expects a single `emu` ( `sub DoMyJob(byref F as emu...` ) ought not even compile.  An array of structure of objects?  Its all very messy and probably wont compile under `Option Strict`

Comment: that was my mistake, I am new to this forum,and I tried to to edit but it did not allow me to edit, sorry for that. The actual code is as below:

public sub goEMU_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles goEMU.click

   ******Some work
Set Index as cc based on some custom criteria
    DoMyJob(x(cc),y)

    *****Some work

end sub

Comment: Please update the question. Don't post code in the comments

Comment: Sorry for that, I am new to this forum so was not aware. Still stuck with the problem. Any suggestion please.